# errors while uploading images in php

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: picture in C:\xampp\htdocs\page1.php on line 33
>
> Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\page1.php on line 35
> Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded. User Logged in

```
//<?PHP
//session_start();
//if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    //header ("Location: page2.php");/
//}
//?>  
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Basic Login Script</title>


    </head>
    <body>
    
        
    <?php
           
            
            session_start();
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $passwor = "";
            $dbname = "form";
            $name = $_SESSION['login_user'];
            echo $name; 
    
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=form", $username, $passwor);
        
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users where username='$name'");
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo "Connected successfully";      
       $target_dir= "htdocs" ."basketball/";
       $target_file = '$target_dir' .basename($_FILES['picture']['name']); //heres an error    
       $uploadOk = 1;
       $imageFileType=pathinfo('$targetfile','PATHINFO_EXTENSION');//heres an error
       
       if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
       {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);
        if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
       }   
    else {
           echo "File is not an image.";
           $uploadOk = 0;
          }
}
       if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
       {
         echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
       } 
       if ($uploadOk == 0) 
       {
         echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
       } 
       else 
       {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["picture"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
     ?>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
User Logged in<br/><br/>
<form action="page1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="picture" type="file" value="picture">
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>

<P>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
//$_SESSION['user_login'] = '';
//die;
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");}
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: use `isset()` or `!empty()`. Fix this `Notice: Undefined index: picture in C:\xampp\htdocs\page1.php on line 33` and the rest will follow.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well the first thing is: What is the question here?

Comment: @Rizier123 it's *self-explanatory* - Meep meep!

Comment: You cannot put `session_start()` *after* you have output HTML.

Comment: @JayBlanchard They've commented that part out *Sam* - no idea why.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and added it back in as the first line of PHP code. *Weird Ralph*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Very Sam*

Comment: Honestly , this is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that first warning because you're using that entire code inside the same file and not using `isset()` or `!empty()` on your `$_FILES` array.

Use a conditional statement for this line and change the single quotes to doubles. Variables do not get parsed inside single quotes.

```
$target_file = '$target_dir' .basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
```

as in

```
if(!empty($_FILES['picture'])){
   $target_file = "$target_dir" .basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
...
}
```

do that, and the rest will follow.

- Also make sure the folder has proper permissions to write to.

However this line:

```
$target_dir= "htdocs" ."basketball/"
```

is unclear and would read as `htdocsbasketball` as the folder. If that isn't what you want and that those are sub-folders, then add a `/` after `htdocs`.

---

You also don't have an element to match your conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

which what I think is associated with your submit button being named `name="Upload Now"`

That should read as `name="submit"`

You may also want to remove the `value="picture"` from
`<input name="picture" type="file" value="picture">` that could give you problems.

---

You're also outputting before header, so uncomment the first part of your code, and get rid of the `session_start();` where you have it now.

Move `session_start();` where it's located above `$servername = "localhost";` and use

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Login Script</title>
...
```

---

Sidenote:

- Add `exit;` after header, otherwise your code may want to continue executing.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=form", $username, $passwor);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

To catch other potential errors.

---

Footnotes:

- This line `if(isset($_POST['logout'])){` - Your posted code doesn't have an element named "logout" for it, unless it's irrelevant.
- Since you are using PDO, why not benefit from using [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)?